# getNOAA.bathy - Error in if (ncol(x) == 3 & !exists("bathy", inherits = FALSE)) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, package, raster

I already looked at the forum in Github and I did what they mentioned but still is not working. I updated the version of the library (rgdal) and library (raster) and my lON and LAT don't have decimals.

I update all the packages, the marmap packages I installed form CRAN and GibHub neither seem to work

```
ETPBathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -98, lon2 = -79, lat1 = 7, lat2 = -6, resolution = 1)
```

> ETPBathy <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = -98, lon2 = -79, lat1 = 7, lat2 = -6, resolution = 1)
> Querying NOAA database ...
> This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size
> Error in if (ncol(x) == 3 & !exists("bathy", inherits = FALSE)) { :
> argument is of length zero

```
Still not working, maybe the R version? Does anyone know what to do in this case?
```

Comment: What version of `R` and `marmap` are you using? And are you on Windows, Mac or Linux? It's working as expected on my side with `marmap_1.0.8` and `raster_3.6-3` (`R 4.2.2`) on MacOS Ventura

Comment: Could be connected to https://github.com/ericpante/marmap/pull/28

Comment: I can confirm I get the same error even when just using the code from the vignette. Error appears to be thrown by `raster::raster()` when it calls `basename()` with the core error being that the path is too long. I'm also on `R 4.2.2` with `marmap_1.0.8` and `raster_3.6-11`. Might be worth opening a bug report on the github.

Comment: I'm using R (4.2.2), marmap (1.08) ans raster (3.6.11) in windows and still is not working

Comment: You should have a look at [this GH issue](https://github.com/ericpante/marmap/issues/25#issuecomment-965834490). Installing an older version of `raster` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Done, and doesn't work either!! Rversion 4.2.2                                             
packageVersion("raster")
[1] ‘3.4.13’
> packageVersion("marmap")
[1] ‘1.0.8’

Answer (score 0):

`marmap v1.0.9` is now available on GitHub:

```
remotes::install_github("ericpante/marmap")
```

This version should solve the infamous Error message encountered by some (most ?) Windows users:

```
Error in if (ncol(x) == 3 & !exists("bathy", inherits = FALSE)) { :
argument is of length zero
```

I have been able to confirm that the error was due to a limitation in the length of urls that the `raster` package can handle on Windows. The geotif files from NOAA's servers are now downloaded with `utils::download.file()` in a temporary file on the user's disk and then imported in R using `raster::raster()`.

`marmap v1.0.9` will be available on CRAN servers in the next few days.